# Contradictory outputs in dictionary key value in for-loop mode in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

To understand the contraction(in ending paragraphs) first you need to observe these four scenario carefully with eagle eye:
(ignore silly mistakes if found any, understand the stuff for what the question is)

1st:

```
r={'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'}
print(r[A])#this gives error as "A" in not inside Quotation marks
```

2nd:

```
r={'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'}
print(r['A'])   #now there is no error in output result
```

3rd:

```
r={'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'}
for xyz in r:
    print(r[A])   # again there will be error in output result 
                  # because "A" is not inside quotation marks.
```

4rd:

```
r={'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'}
for xyz in r:
    print(r['A'])   #not no error will be there as "A" is inside  
                    #quotation marks
```

contradiction starts from here in loop

5th:

```
 r={'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'}
 for xyz in r:
     print(xyz)       #output result come as A C B with no quotation 
                           mark, you can check to see
```

6th:

```
 r={'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'}
 for xyz in r:
     print(r[A])    # shows error in output as "A" is not inside  
                        # quotation marks
```

7th:

```
 r={'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'}
 for xyz in r:
     print(r['A'])  #result comes out successfully as aa aa aa with new 
                         line inbetween
```

8th:

```
r={'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'}
for xyz in r:
    print(r['xyz']) #result should come successfully as r['xyz'] means  
                          r['A'] or r['B'] or r['C'] in the loop
                         #but it shows error which by omitting the quotation      
                          mark of xyz show the result successful as shown in
                          9th scenario
```

9th:

```
r={'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'}
for xyz in r:
    print(r[xyz])   #output result comes successfully as aa cc bb 
                             (check to see)
```

Contradiction: in 9th scenario literally print(r[xyz]) without quotation marks around xyz means print(r[A]) or print(r[B]) or print(r[C]) which shows successful output result, and which in 8th scenario print(r['xyz']) shows up with error in its output result. 
now this is contradictory to:

- 1st scenario, 3rd scenario and 6th scenario where print(r[A]) shows
        error because "A" wasn't inside quotation marks which in...
- 2nd scenario, 4th scenario and 7th scenario by putting "A" inside
        quotation marks gives the result successfully.

Now my question is quotation marks or without marks?? is there one universal rule for it or more than one rule??

Comment: You are confusing strings and variables. Your keys in `r` are strings. You can put those strings in a variable and use the variable to look up a corresponding value.

Comment: There are no contradictions here, only a misunderstanding what is a variable and what is a string value. Quotes make a string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down into stages, to see if that helps. I'm going to assume you're happy that the `for` loop `for xyz in r:` is equivalent to doing:

```
xyz = 'A'
# Do the contents of the loop
xyz = 'B'
# Do the contents of the loop
xyz = 'C'
# Do the contents of the loop
```

So to make the example simpler, we can look at this case:

```
r = {'A':'aa', 'B':'bb', 'C':'cc'}
xyz = 'A'
```

Now, if we do:

```
print(r[xyz])
```

This does several things.

1. `xyz` is not in quotes, so Python treats it as a label (or 'name') for something
2. `xyz` is indeed a label! It's a variable that contains the value `'A'`, a string.
3. Python swaps in the *value* of `xyz`, so the print statement we're going to execute now looks like `print(r['A'])`
4. Python checks to see if the string `'A'` is a key in the dictionary `r`. It is!
5. The value of the entry for the key `'A'` is `'aa'`, also a string, so the print statement now looks like this: `print('aa')`. There's nothing else to look up, so this is what python executes.

If we try to do:

```
print(r['xyz'])
```

1. `'xyx'` is a literal string, so python tries to see if there is an entry in `r` that has the key `'xyz'`
2. There is no key called `'xyz'` in `r`, so python displays an error

Next up:

```
print(r[A])
```

1. `A` is not in quotes, so Python treats it as a label for something
2. No label with the name `A` exists in the program, so Python can't look up it's value!
3. Python displays an error because it can't look up the value of `A`

Hopefully this clears up the quote difference.

Comment: xyz is not equal to 'A' or 'B' or 'C'. But xyz = A or B or C, no quotation. Run the program of my 5th scenario and you will get to see the values of xyz

Comment: I disagree completely. The keys in your dictionary are strings `'A'` `'B'` and `'C'`, they are not the names `A` `B` and `C` without quotes. This means that `xyz` gets the strings, in quotes.

Comment: Your 5th scenario does not print out the quote marks, because they are how _your script_ tells whether or not something is a string. If you do `print("hello")` you don't see `"hello"` displayed, you just see `hello` - without quote marks. But `print` can only show strings

Comment: I don't say that at all. I say it looks like `print(r['A'])`, _with_ quotes.

Comment: Oh Fish!! i was wrong!! thank you so much Simon!! i appreciate you for clearing me out!! i have a very bad habit that i clear things out until i get cleared logically, or else it dont get digested!! thanks again buddy!!

Comment: "If you do print("hello") you don't see "hello", your this example made me clear!! i misunderstood!!

Answer (score 1):

`xyz` is a name (or label) for an object. The loop points the name `xyz` to each key in the dictionary. So using `xyz` as a key is fine, because its value is actually `'A'`, then `'B'`, then `'C'`.

`'xyz'` is a string being used as a key to the dictionary.
The dictionary doesn't have a key `'xyz'` so fails.

`A` is an unbound name. It hasn't been defined to point to any object. The interpreter doesn't know what you are talking about when you say `r[A]`. It knows what the name `r` is; it points to a dictionary object. But `A` is unknown to it.

`'A'` is a string. The dictionary has the key `'A'` in it so matches and doesn't fail.

edit:

In the question you say:

> `r['xyz']` means `r['A']` or `r['B']` or `r['C']` in the loop

This is not true.

Every time through the loop, `r['xyz']` means `r['xyz']`.

This says to the dictionary:

> "do you have a key with value `'xyz'`?

and the dictionary looks at its keys, which are `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'`, and says:

> "no, there is no key `'xyz'`"

Comment: note i did a typing mistake in 7th scenario in comment part, its out put result there is actually aa aa aa with new line between them (not A A A with new line between them as i typed mistakely). i will edit that now. and i am coming with my reply soon in few minute.

Comment: (i)-- 1st let it be cleared that in the loop, xyz acts as a key without 
quotation(see the result of 5th scenario), so proved.
Now.........(ii) In 7th scenario, output of print(r['A']) is aa aa aa which proves that the key(as the key A here) should be inside quotation to get its value output, or else error will pop-up as in 6th........  
   IN the same way, print(r['xyz']) (where xyz acts as a key without quotation as explained in 1st para) should show the output result of its value successfully without any error as in 7th scenario explained above

Comment: `'xyz'` is not the same as `xyz`. `'xyz'` is a literal string object. `xyz` is a name for an object which could have value `'A'` for example. `'xyz'` is not the value of a key in the dictionary. `'A'` is the value of a key in the dictionary.

Comment: i know that 'xyz' and xyz is different. i just tried to discuss it in less technical way!! i know these two are completely different!!... your focus went on the different track!

Comment: @Andrew you are not being clear at all in what you are saying. I've tried to explain as best as I can in the time available to me.

Comment: I don't think his focus went on a different track. The key is `'A'`, a string. if the variable `xyz` contains the string `'A'` then doing `r[xyz]` will use the *value* of the variable `xyz` as the key. If you do `r['xyz']` then you are looking up the `key` `'xyz'`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @SimonFraser compare the result of "8th and 9th" with "6th and 7th" by checking the value of xyz(variable) in the output result of 5th..................................... so now concentrate here, by replacing xyz with A or B or C in (as the variable of xyz in loop, check 5th) 9th will become 6th, and then now check the result of 9th and 6th now........in the same way transform the 8th by the value of xyz and 8th will become 7th, and then compare 8th and 7th...!! .... hope now my point is clear to you

Comment: I understand your question, so no need to tell me to concentrate :) I've moved to writing an answer as my explanation was too long for a comment.

Comment: @SimonFraser dont misunderstand my word "concentrate"!! its not sarcasm buddy :) sharing knowledge should be peacefull... btw in ur update my doubts got cleared, thanks :) !!

Answer (score 0):

9th and 8th scenario are not contradictions to previous ones.In python when you declare a for statement like the following

```
mylist = ["a", "b", "c"]
for each in mylist:
    print(each)
```

In this statement print statement executes 3 times. In first `each` is equal to  `a`. In second it is equal to `b` and in third it is equal to `c`. So in a for loop the word after the `for` is equal to the elements in your list.
 When you try to execute

```
 for each in mylist:
        print(a)
```

It will not work because you are trying to print a variable `a` which does not exist. In your case, when you write `xyz` you make it equal to the keys in your dictionary so you can write `print(r[xyz])`.

In 8th scenario you are trying to get the value associated with the key `xyz`. Since you do not have a key `xyz` your code fails.

In your 5th scenario your print(xyz) returns A and B and C.If you try to print something like "Hello World" it will write Hello World not "Hello World".The fact that it wrote Hello World" will not change the fact that print had the argument of "Hello World".

For further understanding you can test this.

```
for each in mylist:
    if each=="a":
        print(each)
```

This will print a one time proving that each is equal to "a" and not a.One more example to clarify things.
    You wrote that when you printed xyz you got A as a result so "xyz" should be "A".This is wrong.When you write something inside " " it means that they will be a string and they will not call their value if they have one.Test this.

```
val=3
if "val"=="3":
    print ("something")
```

This will not print something because "val" equals to "val" not "3"

Conclusion : When you write print(r[xyz])it does not mean print(r[A]).It means print(r["A"])

Comment: u misunderstood my conclusion part of contradiction and got it wrong!!

Comment: (i)-- 1st let it be cleared that in the loop, xyz acts as a key without 
quotation(see the result of 5th scenario)....... .......(ii) Now here is the cache, In 7th scenario, output of print(r['A']) is aa aa aa which proves that the key(as the key A here) should be inside quotation to get its value output, or else error will pop-up as in 6th........  
   IN the same way, print(r['xyz']) (where xyz acts as a key without quotation as explained in 1st para) should show the output result of its value successfully without any error as in 7th scenario explained above

Comment: @Andrew please don't copy and paste comments. We are not machines.

Comment: I explained it to you in my answer but I will explain it again.When you write print(r["A"]) you want the value in your dictionary r which is associated with "A".That value is aa so it is correct.When you write print(r["xyz"]) you want the value in your dictionary r which is associated with "xyz".But you dont have a key named "xyz".When you define something with for in your dictionary it becomes the keys.I understood that in your 5th scenario you think xyz is equal to A and not "A" but that is not the case.When you try to print a string "A" in python it writes A but it is equal to "A".

Comment: I am updating my answer to provide you a better and cleaner answer